# Configuring Postgres Driver (Connector) for tomcat7

Tags: postgresql, jsp, jdbc, tomcat7, mysql-connector

I have been trying to get my jsp code having some postgresql queries to work. I don't know what seems to be the problem, whether it is a problem with the configuration of the jdbc Driver or there is a problem with my code.

Here is the configuration in context.xml .

```
<Resource name="jdbc/filedb" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/testdb"
          username="akshay" password="akshay" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
maxWait="-1"/>
```

I also want to know what is resource name. Here I have added the table name whichis filedb.

This is how server.xml looks.

```
 <GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource name="jdbc/filedb" auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="akshay" 
          password="akshay"
          driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/testdb"
          maxActive="20" 
          maxIdle="10"
          maxWait="-1"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

I tried to run with and also without the above configuration.

This is what I've added to web.xml

```
  <resource-ref>
 <description>postgreSQL Datasource example</description>
 <res-ref-name>jdbc/filedb</res-ref-name>
 <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
 <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

This is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form name=f1 method=Post action="http://localhost:8080/filedb1.jsp">

<table>
<td>
Add Header 1<input type=text name=header1 id=header1>
</td><td>
Add Header 2<input type=text name=header2 id=header2>
</td><td>
Add Header 3<input type=text name=header3 id=header3>
</td><td>
Add Header 4<input type=text name=header4 id=header4>
</td>
<tr>
<td>
Upload File 1<input type=file name=path1 id=file1></td><td>
Upload File 2<input type=file name=path2 id=file2></td><td>
Upload File 3<input type=file name=path3 id=file3></td><td>
Upload File 4<input type=file name=path4 id=file4></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div align="center">
<input type=submit value="SUBMIT" onclick="f1.action='http://localhost:8080/filedb1.jsp';return true;">
</div>
</form>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page language="java" session="true" %>

<%
   String file1 = request.getParameter("file1");
   String file2 = request.getParameter("file2");
   String file3 = request.getParameter("file3");
   String file4 = request.getParameter("file4");
   String header1 = request.getParameter("header1");
   String header2 = request.getParameter("header2");
   String header3 = request.getParameter("header3");
   String header4 = request.getParameter("header4");
   java.sql.Connection con;
   con=null;
   
   PreparedStatement psmt=null;
   PreparedStatement psmt1=null;
   PreparedStatement psmt2=null;
   PreparedStatement psmt3=null;

   try{
   Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
   con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/testdb","akshay","akshay");
   psmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into filedb(id,header,content)"+"values (?,?,?)");
   psmt.setInt(1,1);
   psmt.setString(2,header1);
   psmt.setString(3,file1);
   int s = psmt.executeUpdate();
   %> <font color="orange"> 
  <%
    if(s>0) 
     {
      %><%out.println("File Name :"+file1+" added to database.");%><%
     }
    else
     {
     %><%out.println("File Name :"+file1+" unsuccessfull attempt while adding to database.");%><%
     }   
   psmt1=con.prepareStatement("insert into filedb(id,header,content)"+"values (?,?,?)");
   psmt1.setInt(1,2);
   psmt1.setString(2,header2);
   psmt1.setString(3,file2);
   int s1 = psmt1.executeUpdate();
  if(s1>0) 
     {
      out.println("File Name :"+file2+" added to database.");
     }
    else
     {
     out.println("File Name :"+file2+" unsuccessfull attempt while adding to database.");
     }   
   psmt2=con.prepareStatement("insert into filedb(id,header,content)"+"values (?,?,?)");
   psmt2.setInt(1,3);
   psmt2.setString(2,header3);
   psmt2.setString(3,file3);
   int s2 = psmt2.executeUpdate();
  if(s2>0) 
     {
      out.println("File Name :"+file3+" added to database.");
     }
    else
     {
     out.println("File Name :"+file3+" unsuccessfull attempt whileadding to database.");
     }   
   psmt3=con.prepareStatement("insert into filedb(id,header,content)"+"values (?,?,?)");
   psmt3.setInt(1,4);
   psmt3.setString(2,header4);
   psmt3.setString(3,file4);
   int s3 = psmt3.executeUpdate();
  if(s3>0) 
     {
      out.println("File Name :"+file4+" added to database.");
     }
    else
     {
     out.println("File Name :"+file4+" unsuccessfull attempt whileadding to database.");
     }   
    psmt1.close();
  psmt2.close();
  psmt3.close();
  psmt.close();
  con.commit();
  con.close();
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
  ex.printStackTrace();
  }

%> 

</font>

</body>
</html>
```

Table filedb

```
    Table "public.filedb"
 Column  |  Type   | Modifiers 
---------+---------+-----------
 id      | integer | not null
 header  | text    | not null
 content | text    | not null
```

I don't get any errors but there is no update in the table. There are no new records.

I apologize for the bad indentation and the trivial nature of my problem but I have not been able to surpass it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: **Please** don't put JDBC code into your JSPs! Try adding a space before `VALUES` in your `INSERT` statements. Try adding a `con.commit();` before you `con.close();`. Please edit to include your Postgres schema; normally you have Postgres provide id(s) on insert.

Comment: I haven't created a schema. I will remember all the corrections. It doesn't work after making the changes. Is there something wrong with the configuration.

Comment: Do you have a `testdb` with a table named `filedb`?

Comment: Yes I have a database testdb with a table named filedb .Do I need to add or change something somewhere in the configuration. I have my Driver in the folder tomcat/lib.

Comment: I have the <resource-ref> tag in web.xml just after <web-app xmlns> tag.

Comment: I don't think so, you aren't getting a Datasource exception. Please post the schema of `filedb` from `testdb`.

Comment: filedb(id int,header text,content text) this is how the table looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I used mysql connector instead.

This is what I added to web.xml

```xml
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/test</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Here is what I added to context.xml

```xml
<Resource name="jdbc/filedb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
    username="akshay" password="akshay" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true"/>
```

And lastly this is what went inside server.xml

```xml
<Resource name="jdbc/filedb" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="akshay"
          password="akshay"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test"
          maxActive="20"
          maxIdle="10"
          maxWait="-1"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
```

I don't know why its not working with postgresql but the code is actually the same.